# Footer links to call a phtml page

Tags: magento-1.8, xml, phtml

I am new to Magento and just learning.  Tried something and got stuck.

I have a footer.phtml and it has a few links.  One link is "Terms & Conditions" and I have a page called terms.phtml

When someone click "terms and conditions"  want to load the page terms.phtml in the "contents" block.

In the local.xml file I add this

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template"  name="terms" as="terms" template="page/html/terms.phtml" />
</reference>

</default>
```

But it is not working.  Please help me

1) what should I give in the a href for terms and conditions

Terms & Conditions

2) What should I write in the local.xml

3) how to call the block in href to load the Contents

Answer (score 2):

1. create a cms page for that follow this [link](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_home_design.htm)
2. use the `url key` in `href`

you don't need to add xml set the page layout if you want. you can also see the page by clicking the preview

Comment: Very much greatful , but I want to remove the home page contents and then load the terms and conditions,  any suggestions please

Comment: mean no header footer?

Comment: I did the same, but works great. But the original body contents still there and the terms comes after the home contents,  Am i doing wrong

Comment: <reference name="root">
   <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
    <label>New Reference</label>
   </block>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
   <block type="core/template" name="newreference" template="page/html/ebaycatg1.phtml" />
  </reference>

Comment: r u created the new page?

Comment: yes, I have the page ebaycatg.phtml, worked around, but the homepage contents is coming twice  bibliografi.co.uk and when you click the bottom terms and conditions, the contents is replaced as you suggested

Comment: pls help, will be greatful if you can

Comment: i am asking about in admin  cms page?

Comment: yes, I created in admin cms

Comment: key-url and direct click on preview show the home page content too. where you add xml code??

Comment: I added in local.xml ,  I have a page called xyz.phtml and on click a href i want to show the page xyz.phtml in the content block, please can you help

Comment: {{block type="core/template_list" template="page/html/ebaycatg1.phtml"}}  add this code in your cms page content then check and remove the xml code from local